# allow hotlinking image but redirect to php script

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'd like to allow hotlinking to images i.e allow

```
<a href="http://example.com/image.php/image.jpg">
    <img src="http://example.com/image.php/image.jpg">
</a>
```

from an external site. But if clicked on use htaccess to redirect to a script that displays html.

I'm thinking .htaccess could redirect to image.php to display a a regular image for hotlinkers and image-html.php for anyone that clicked from the hotlinked image.

Is this possible with htaccess?

Comment: You can check for the presence of a referer header using mod_rewrite, but referers are NOT reliable and will always cause problems for this type of action.

Comment: Thanks Marc, we're curretnly using mod_rewrite and detecting headers but we're not able to differenciate hotlinking from an actual browser visit.

Comment: You can definetly do this with htaccess.

Have a look at this website or simply google for:
htaccess prevent hotlinking images

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess10.shtml
If you look at the second code example it says:

    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ http://www.mydomain.com/angryman.gif [R,L]

So it simply checks: "Is this request for the image from my own domain or does it come from another- If it is not from my own domain than show another picture"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there's absolutely no difference in the HTTP headers between clicking on an `<a href="yourimage">` and and `<img src="yourimage">` when both are on a remote page. Both will have the same HTTP Referer - the address of the page the image and link are hosted on. Both will simply be seen as a request for the image. You could try some timing calculations - the embedded image would be loaded at time 'X', and clicking on the link would come in at time Y. But again this is unreliable and subject to gaming.

To reliably differentiate, you'd need to have different urls. Even appending a bogus query string, such as doing `<img src="yourimage?src=imgtag">` would help, but this presumes you have some kind of control over where/how the image gets linked/hotlinked.